# Text size in pdf exported

Tags: export, pdf-format, size

I would like to know how could I manage text size when I export my whole .nb to .pdf, specifically to make fit in my document in only 2 pages instead of 3 being the third page just with few lines written.

Thank you so much and sorry if it is duplicated.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Well, I've done this printing .nb as PDF and adjusting margins, but this is a nice workaround, since I've fitted in my document in 2 pages, as I did want, but I've not managed the text size, I would like to know if I could do this.